# C# Override method with subclass parameter

Tags: c#, overriding, subclass

I'm trying to achieve something like this

```
public abstract class BaseEvent
{
    public abstract void Dispatch(IEventHandler handler);
}

public class MyEvent : BaseEvent
{
    public override void Dispatch(IMyEventHandler handler)
    {
        handler.OnMyEvent(this);
    }
}

public interface IEventHandler
{
}

public interface IMyEventHandler : IEventHandler
{
    void OnMyEvent(MyEvent e);
}
```

The problem is that the compiler complains saying that `MyEvent` doesn't implement `BaseEvent` since `Dispatch` is taking an `IMyEventHandler` instead of an `IEventHandler`. I don't want to let `MyEvent.Dispatch` take a `IEventHandler` then cast it to a `IMyEventHandler` because I would like compile time checks to make sure I'm not doing something stupid like passing in some other type of event handler. I found a possible solution (below) but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way of doing this.

```
public abstract class BaseEvent<H> where H : IEventHandler
{
    public abstract void Dispatch(H handler);
}

public class MyFirstEvent<H> : BaseEvent<H> where H : IMyFirstEventHandler
{
    public override void Dispatch(H handler)
    {
        handler.OnMyFirstEvent(this);
    }
}

public interface IEventHandler
{
}

public interface IMyFirstEventHandler : IEventHandler
{
    void OnMyFirstEvent<H>(MyFirstEvent<H> e) where H : IMyFirstEventHandler;
}
```

Thanks, Tom

Comment: I think you can replace `MyFirstEvent<H> : BaseEvent<H> where H : IMyFirstEventHandler` with `MyFirstEvent : BaseEvent<IMyFirstEventHandler>`. Depends on what you want though (i.e. whether you want to allow passing in a type parameter to `MyFirst`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used your approach before.

It looks pretty solid to me.

Comment: Do you know if there is a name for this pattern?

Comment: @Tom: I haven't heard of a name for this pattern, but when I first used it, I thought it was a classic use-case for .NET generics. Emphasis: It was the *correct* usage of .NET generics. [I've seen many *incorrect* usages of .NET generics.]

Comment: I did a similar pattern in C++ years ago and it was called [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

Answer (score -3):

MyEvent change the abstract method Dispatch's signature. so you got a compile time error.

how about follow code.

```
public class MyEvent : BaseEvent
{
    public override void Dispatch(IEventHandler handler)
    {
        if(!handler is IMyFirstEventHandler )throw new ArgumentException("message").
        ((IMyFirstEventHandler )handler).OnMyEvent(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not give a compilation error. Doing the wrong thing here would only result in a runtime exception.

Answer (score -4):

This seems pretty similar to [Help With Overriding and Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337598/help-with-overriding-and-inheritance). I'm pretty confident you need to the keyword 'virtual' if you want to override a method.

Comment: Methods need to be virtual OR abstract; [This link](http://www.compiledthoughts.com/2008/03/abstract-vs-virtual-explained.html) sums up the difference pretty nicely. Anyway, that's not the problem; the problem is that the method that my derived class is supposed to be overriding needs to take as a parameter a subclass of the parameter that the base method takes.