# How do I use method overriding in this case?

Tags: c#, overriding

So this is my class and I just learned a little bit about inheritance. I heard about overriding methods but how do I do it in this case?

```
class Game
{
    string consoleName;
    int gameID;

    public Game(string name, int id)
    {
        this.consoleName = name;
        this.gameID = id;
    }

   public string displayGame()
   {
        return consoleName + " is the console I am playing";
   }
```

Here is my child class.

```
class RolePlayingGame : Game
{
    int level;

    public RolePlayingGame(string name, int id, int lv) : base(string name, int id)
    {
         this.level = lv;
    }

    // override method for displaying. meant to display what the game class displayed and "I am level " + level
}
```

Comment: See this question and first answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/337598/1741542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the your base class first:

```
class Game
{
   ...
   public virtual string displayGame()
   {
       return consoleName + " is the console I am playing";
   }
}
```

In your inherited class (child class),

```
class RolePlayingGame : Game
{
     ...
     public override string displayGame()
     {
         ...
         base.displayGame();  // If you need to call the base class.
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `displayGame()` in `Game` class to be virtual.

In `RolePlayingGame` override like this:

```
public override string displayGame() {
    return base.displayGame() + " - I am level " + level;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do. In `class Game` you have to declare the method virtual.

```
public virtual string DisplayGame(){ ... }
```

Then in `class RolePlayingGame` you have to declare that you are overriding the method, `override`. (You could also hide the method using `new`.)

```
public override string DisplayGame(){ ... }
```

Here is some more information on overriding vs. hiding from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make DisplayGame() a virtual method in Game class.

> ```
> public virtual string displayGame() { ... }
> ```

1. In RolePlayingGame, define the overriding method

> ```
> public override string displayGame() 
> { 
>   return String.Format("Game {0}, Level {1}", this.name, this.level); 
> }
> ```

By the way, you need a member "string name" to store the name of the Game in Game class.

You can refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9fkccyh4.aspx. There are some good and simple examples that you can follow.