# Unity Microphone not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I am trying to build a VR Lobby where users can talk to each other.
I struggle with the basic code I found on the Unitywebsite.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetMicrophoneInput : MonoBehaviour
{
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start()
  {
    var audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 10, 44100);
    audio.loop = true;
    while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0))
    {

    }

    audio.Play();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {

  }
}
```

The first one is about `Microphone.Start()`. It says I cannot use `Start()`, because it is Protected.
The second is about `Microphone.GetPosition()`. It says Microphone does not have a definition for GetPosition.

Both used to work in previous versions of Unity.

I am using Unity 5.6.2.

Any ideas how I get this working again? Thanks.

Comment: Put the exact error messages. Your second error is probably your Microphone just bein null? This Code works for me completly fine. I am on Unity 5.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Not a Unity expert, but I believe the problem is that you're `GetMicrophoneInput` class is inheriting the `MonoBehavior` class and trying to create a method called `Start()` when the MonoBehavior class already has a start method. If you want to have your `Start()` method perform different functions in addition to the base MonoBehavior class, then you'll need to declare your `Start` method as:

```
protected override void Start()
{
var audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
audio.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 10, 44100);
audio.loop = true;
while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0))
{

}

audio.Play();
base.Start();//This tells your code to do what the base MonoBehavior class would do in the start method.
}
```

If you don't want your method to override the base `Start()` method, then simply name your method something else :). However, the same goes for your `Update` method as it's a function inside the `MonoBehaviour` class as well.

In regards to your `Microphone.GetPosition` question, the [Microphone class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html) DOES have a GetPosition funciton, but a parameter into the function is the deviceName. Perhaps you need to pass in "Built-In Microphone" instead of null.

[MonoBehavior Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)

[More info on overriding inherited class functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337598/help-with-overriding-and-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks. I just fixed the problem. It was very stupid. Someone had created an additional  Microphone class which got used instead of unity`s class.I just deleted this class and now everything is working just fine.